# Access session value from iframe URL hosted on different domain

Tags: java, grails

I want to access session value from iframe hosted on a different domain.

I have an action in our Grails application, where I am setting value in a session of our domain, and then redirecting to another domain which has integrated iframe of our domain URL:

```
def action1= {
session.name = "John"
redirect(uri:"https://anotherdomain.com/page1")
}

on https://anotherdomain.com/page1 we have code like below

<iframe src="https://ourdomain.com/action2" style="width: 100%;height: 100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>

def action2={
    log.debug "getting value from session ${session.name}"
}
```

It is always printing null.

I just want to access that value in action2.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions variable are specific to a host or cluster of hosts (when using sessions replication). You will not be able to do this with a standard session variable.

Comment: Do we have alternate solution for this, please suggest me, using grails 1.2.1 and jdk 1.7

Comment: You would have to build a system similar to session replication but for different domains. So part of it would live in one server/app (domain), and the other part would live in the other server/app (domain) and would publish values from session variables into another structure that you could look up on either end.